# Jenkins declarative pipeline configuring the agent using shared library

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy, multibranch-pipeline

I would like to be able to specify the agent based on a parameter in my shared library groovy file.  I know the following example will work but it requires me to copy the pipeline twice:

```
// vars/selectAgent.groovy
def call(String agent) {
  if (agent === "any") {
    pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
          steps {
            echo "ran on any agent"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    pipeline {
      agent {
         label "$agent"
      }
      stages {
        stage(‘Stage1') {
          steps {
            echo "The build ran on agent label ${agent}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create an agent statement which would be rendered either as

```
agent any
```

or

```
agent {
  label 'myLabel'
}
```

without having to repeat the whole pipeline?  Please note that my pipeline is much more longer than this simple example.  I looked into GroovyASTTransform but I have no idea how this works, if it would be possible and how to do it.

Obviously I would want my Jenkinsfile to contain either

```
selectAgent('any')
```

or

```
selectAgent('myLabel')
```

Comment: I suggest putting the if condition under the stage and use when a condition, `jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when`

Comment: @袁文涛 your suggestion addresses the conditional execution of a step. It does not address my problem which is to pick different agent configuration based on a condition without having to duplicate the pipeline. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @mario, did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Christopher no I have never did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stage level Agent Selection, and add expression as a condition. In this way you are going to execute only 1 stage for your external argument.

```
def call(String agent) {
    pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Even Stage') {
            when {
                expression { ${params.agent} == 'any' }
            }
            agent {label 'agent1'} 
            steps {
                echo "The build number is even"
            }
        }
        stage('Odd Stage') {
            when {
                expression { !${params.agent} == 'any' }
            }
            agent {label 'agent2'} 
            steps {
                echo "The build number is odd"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Note:** The Pipeline is not tested but it should work.

Comment: your example does not address the question. I want to be able to select either agent any or agent {label “$agent”} in a shared library. I don’t want to duplicate the pipeline in my shared library